# Xamarin Forms List view - Data template into columns

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, datagridview

How could I achieve two columns using only a Xamarin Forms listview? Can someone share an example? I'm trying to avoid using DLToolkit or any other plugin.

[image]

Comment: use CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

Comment: Thanks @Jason . I got an error . The class, property, or method you are attempting to use ('VerifyCollectionViewFlagEnabled') is part of CollectionView; to use it, you must opt-in by calling Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental") before calling Forms.Init().

Comment: It worked!. thanks! I had to add Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental"); on the app.cs

Comment: @Pxaml, It seems that you Jason's reply has solved your issue, can you share your solution here and mark it an answer,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   <CollectionView x:Name="clv"  ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" >ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveItems}” Margin="20" Header="{Binding .}"  >
>           <CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
>                 <DataTemplate>
>                     <Grid>
>                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
>                             <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
>                         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>
>                         <Label Text="Select " HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
>                                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" InputTransparent="True" />
>                         </Grid>
>                 </DataTemplate>
>             </CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
>    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
>        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalItemSpacing="20"
>                         Span="2" />
>     </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
>       <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
>         <DataTemplate>
>              <Grid >
>                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                     <RowDefinition Height="150" />
>                     <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
>
>                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
>                     <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
>                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>
>                 <Image Grid.Row="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
>                        Source="Icon"
>                        Aspect="AspectFill"/>
>                    <Label 
>                        Text="{Binding alterName }" FontSize="18"
>                        FontAttributes="Bold"
>                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
>
>                 </StackLayout>
>             </Grid>
>        </DataTemplate>
>     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
> </CollectionView>
> ```